# Unable to scrape as data is present in similar tags so difficult to distinguish

Tags: regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Source Page:

[image: Source Code]

I need to scrape above numerical values like 1,426.0.....809.9....1,270.6 and 1,887.0 using python but regex not hitting for different values as values have similar tags...How to distinguish them any other method to crawl this?? Pls help

Comment: It would be easier if u provide the website's url.

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here's the URL : http://www.attainix.com/ICTrackerSummary.aspx?stockletter=A.IN

Comment: Output I derived using BeautifulSoup <td width="3%"><font color="#284775"> 
                                    58 
                                </font></td>
<td align="right" width="6%"><font color="#284775">406.7</font></td>
<td align="right" width="6%"><font color="Red">289.6</font></td>
<td align="right" width="6%"><font color="Green">443.7</font></td>
<td align="right" width="8%"><font color="#284775">125,213.2</font></td>
<td align="right" width="8%"><font color="#284775">87,649.2</font></td>
Now I WANt to fetch values inside tags

Comment: Ok...I will provide u the solution within 5 minutes.

Comment: One more thing the font colour keeps changing on daily basis so we have to ignore this tag as wel

Comment: Check whether my code does what u need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help u:

```
html = '<td width="3%"><font color="#284775"> 58 </font></td> <td align="right" width="6%"><font color="#284775">406.7</font></td> <td align="right" width="6%"><font color="Red">289.6</font></td> <td align="right" width="6%"><font color="Green">443.7</font></td> <td align="right" width="8%"><font color="#284775">125,213.2</font></td> <td align="right" width="8%"><font color="#284775">87,649.2</font></td>' 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tds = soup.find_all('td')

numlst = []

final_lst = []

for x in tds:
    numlst.append((x.text.replace(" ","")))

for x in numlst:
    num = x.split(",")
    num = ''.join(num)

    try:
        final_lst.append(float(num))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(final_lst)
```

Output:

```
[58.0, 406.7, 289.6, 443.7, 125213.2, 87649.2]
```